# How the fopen in PHP works?

Tags: php, web-scraping, fopen

I was trying this simple PHP code from a book.

```
<?php
$handle=fopen('http://www.abc.com/','r');
//echo $handle;
$response=stream_get_contents($handle);
//echo $response;
$meta=stream_get_meta_data($handle);
//print_r($meta['wrapper_data']);
?>
```

When we call fopen(), it returns file pointer resource(as per PHP manual). When I echoed the value of $handle, it was a simple number. I did not understand what happened in the background. Is it like fopen() downloaded the html and stored in some where , and give us a pointer?

When I echoed $response, it was entire web page as it is. It means $response contains complete HTML of the web page. Now how it got entire HTML from stream_get_contents($handle). but $handle is just a number if we echo it. I can't understand the mechanism of fopen and file pointer resource. can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 0):

The concept is similar with many programming language (especially C).

When a file is being opened, we need a identifier to manipulate (read / write / delete) this file later, which called as file pointer resource.

> When a file is opened by a process using the fopen function, a file
>   handle (file pointer resource) is associated with it until either the
>   process terminates or the handle is closed using the fclose function.
>   The file handle is used to identify the file in many function calls.

More: [File Handles in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)